# Combining optional macros to form a list

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have two preprocessor macros "A" and "B" that need to be combined as an initializer list. E.g.:

```
MyType obj = { A, B };
```

However A may be empty, a single value, or a list, and B may be empty or a single value. So the problem becomes how to avoid inserting a needless comma, i.e. when either A or B is empty.

So a pseudo-CPP-code solution would be:

```
#if EMPTY(B)
MyType obj = { A };
#else
MyType obj = { A, B };
#endif
```

But how to write the `EMPTY()` test such that for `#define A` it is true, for `#define A 1,2,3` it is false? (I've blundered around with helper macros without getting anything likely to compile...)

Note that the macros come from an external configuration mechanism so a CPP-oriented solution like this is a natural fit, rather than the inevitable fair question "why are you doing this with macros?"

Comment: I feel that the heart of this question is how to test if a macro argument is empty. I don't think that's possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define A (a)(b)
#define B (x)(y)(z)

#define SAFE_ENUM(seq) \
    BOOST_PP_IIF( \
        BOOST_PP_IS_BEGIN_PARENS(seq), \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM, \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_EAT(1) \
    )(seq) \
    /**/

MyType obj = { SAFE_ENUM(A B) };
```

A degree of indirection is required because Boost sequences cannot be empty (which it would be if both `A` and `B` are both empty.

** edit **

Using [Chaos.Preprocessor](http://chaos-pp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/chaos-pp/chaos-pp/built-docs/headers.html) instead:

```
#include <chaos/preprocessor/control/inline_unless.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/detection/is_empty.h>
#include <chaos/preprocessor/seq/enumerate.h>

#define A a, b
#define B x, y, z

#define CONVERT(...) \
    CHAOS_PP_INLINE_UNLESS(CHAOS_PP_IS_EMPTY_NON_FUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__))( \
        (__VA_ARGS__) \
    ) \
    /**/

MyType obj = {
    CHAOS_PP_SEQ_ENUMERATE(
        CONVERT(A) CONVERT(B)
    )
};
```

Comment: That looks promising! But I think it still needs the transformation from the starting comma-delimited lists to this parenthetic tuple form, i.e. how to convert from A being "1, 2, 3" to "(1)(2)(3)"? BOOST_PP_ARRAY_TO_SEQ comes close but needs the array length, e.g. converts from "(3, (1,2,3))"

Comment: Why do you require the input being in the form `1, 2, 3`?  I ask because that form will cause problems with templates with multiple template parameters.  E.g. in `std::pair<T, U>` the comma will interfere.  Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Simply because I'd prefer to avoid introducing an additional conversion step between the existing configuration mechanism and the compilation - if that's necessary then the step can just embed this whole optional list construction logic. This is compiling with clang_3.5 and gcc_4.8.1.

Comment: [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) does not have a public interface that can detect the emptiness here (i.e. `A = ` vs `A = 1,2,3`).  You'd have to use [Chaos.Preprocessor](http://chaos-pp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/chaos-pp/chaos-pp/built-docs/headers.html) for that.

Comment: Having skimmed through Chaos - just "wow!". I'd never have dreamed that the CPP could be pressed so far. Mergesorts? This is tech at the indistinguishable-from-magic end of the spectrum :-)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to test whether a macro is defined, but empty at compile time. The pre-compiler allows comparison of integers, ie.

```
#if A > 5
```

but not strings:

```
#if A == ""  // Not allowed!
```

And there's certainly no support for lists. I would say the easiest way to do this is to create an initialiser list for each macro and then combine them at run-time, like:

```
MyType objA = { A };
MyType objB = { B };
// ... now combine them ...
```

Naturally this is very simplistic and highly dependent on your macros, but providing that they are guaranteed to be valid lists, this should work.

Comment: Thanks - I feared that there was no "front door" solution - unfortunately runtime combination looks awkward as the real type is a "constexpr std::array". So far the comma seems the awkward part in attempts with constructor default args and templates - other than arrays and enums trailing commas are bad news. Still holding out hope that some evil (preprocessor) genius will suggest "a plan so crazy it might just work"